# Unobtrusive notification

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to create a notification like redirection alert in firefox in a webextension?

[image: Redirect notification in firefox]

This notification appears on top of the page.

Comment: We are going to need a bit more context to your screenshot in order to know for sure what you are talking about. I can assume, but it is an assumption. You are also going to need to be *explicit* as to what you mean by "notification like", as WebExtensions has [notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications).

Comment: @Makyen I have increased the size of the screenshot. The notification (as I undestood) is desktop notification, isn’t that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible for a WebExtension to create the type of notification which you are asking about.

WebExtensions can create notifications using the [notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications). Such notifications are desktop notifications. How these notifications appear will depend on the OS and windowing system on which the browser is running.

If you desire the type of notification imaged in you question, you could create an API using a [WebExtensions experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which would do what you desire. If adopted, such an API would be migrated into Firefox and become a standard part of WebExtensions.